# Change property of object in array of arrays in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this array of arrays in my viewModel:

```
@Published var calendarButtons  :[[CalendarButton]] = []
```

This array consists of 6 arrays, each of them has 7 elements that make up a set of buttons for a calendar that shows the days of the current month.

```
[[CalendarButton(id: 1238FE48-F24B-4A49-A0AE-ED9F3ED172C9, day: 28, stateDisable: false, activities: [], isSelected: false, _selectedDay: SwiftUI.State<Swift.Int>(_value: 0, _location: nil), onCallBack: (Function), calendarVM: Aya10.CalendarViewModel),seven more CalendarButton()'s ...],[second set of another 7 buttons],[3rd],[4th],[5],[6]]
```

When a button is touched, the isSelected property should change to True and the button that had the isSelected property as true should change to false in order to achieve color changing when selecting a day in the calendar.

I tried with this: When a button is tapped you can read the day on it, with this I tried to search in the array the element that has that day and change the value of selectedDay but it didn't work.

```
for buttons in self.calendarVM.calendarButtons{
    if let row = buttons.firstIndex(where: {$0.day ==  self.day}) {
        print("row: \(row)")
        var buttons = buttons
        buttons[row] = CalendarButton.init(
            day: self.day,
            stateDisable: true,
            activities: self.calendarVM.getActivities(day: self.day, check: self.calendarVM.currentMonth),
            isSelected: true,
            onCallBack: { acts, day in
                //    print("acts: ",acts)
                print("day append: \(day)")
                self.calendarVM.selectedActivies = acts
                self.calendarVM.selectedDay = day
                print("selectedDay en append: \(self.selectedDay)")
            },
            calendarVM: self.calendarVM
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not assigned the modified nested `buttons` array back into the top level `calendarButtons.

```swift
for (index, buttons) in self.calendarVM.calendarButtons.enumerated() {
    if let row = buttons.firstIndex(where: {$0.day ==  self.day}) {
        print("row: \(row)")
        self.calendarVM.calendarButtons[index][row] = CalendarButton.init(
            day: self.day,
            stateDisable: true,
            activities: self.calendarVM.getActivities(day: self.day, check: self.calendarVM.currentMonth),
            isSelected: true,
            onCallBack: { acts, day in
                //    print("acts: ",acts)
                print("day append: \(day)")
                self.calendarVM.selectedActivies = acts
                self.calendarVM.selectedDay = day
                print("selectedDay en append: \(self.selectedDay)")
            },
            calendarVM: self.calendarVM
        )
    }
}
```